# Tate-Shafarevich group of Elkies curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

The Elkies curve
$$
E:y^2+xy+y=x^3−x^2−20067762415575526585033208209338542750930230312178956502x+34481611795030556467032985690390720374855944359319180361266008296291939448732243429
$$
conductor of Elkies curve is
$f=33455601108357547341532253864901605231198511505793733138900595189472144724781456635380154149870961231592352897621963802238155192936274322687070=2\times 3^2\times 5\times 7\times 11\times 13\times 17\times 19\times 48463\times 20650099\times 315574902691581877528345013999136728634663121\times 376018840263193489397987439236873583997122096511452343225772113000611087671413$

We assume the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis (GRH), then $\text{rank}_\mathbb{Z}E(\mathbb{Q})=28$.
If we add the BSD conjecture, can we calculate the order of $Ш(E/\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Sagemath for instance has E.sha().an() for the "analytic order" of Sha, ie the order according to BSD. But I doubt that you can calculate the leading term of the $L$-function of $E$ with such a huge conductor to any precision to determine what it is for this curve.

Comment: Why are interested in this?

Comment: I read an paper where the author gave some estimates of elliptic curve sha group and claimed some order assuming that BSD is true.
For example, let's take the elliptic curve $E:y^2 + xy + y = x^3−x^2−911138880x−10586098442003$,the author asserts $\#Ш(E/\mathbb{Q})=169$ and explains that this is calculated using magma plus BSD. So I was curious to see if I could calculate the sha group Elkies curve by adding BSD.

Comment: Oh but that is very different. That curve has a tiny conductor, in fact it is https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/14450ba2/. You can prove that Sha is of that size without having to assume any conjecture. The speed of calculations of the L-function is going to be something like $O(\sqrt{N})$. For conductors as huge as Elkies' curve that is huge.